# Проблема с подключением в Laravel файла от Bitrix - prolog_before.php

Tags: php, laravel, битрикс

Суть: у меня сервис на Laravel встроен в Bitrix. Всё было отлично, но для соединения с БД Битрикса и использования чего-либо наподобие Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection() нужно было подключить /bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php .

Сделал обычный php файлик, там сделал require(
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
И подключаю этот файлик к моим контроллерам когда нужно - всё ок.

Всё прекрасно работает, битриксовские функции работают, с БД всё взаимодействует, но проблема с php artisan - он теперь выдаёт следующее:

> ErrorException
> require('bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php): Failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory

Если на время закомментить эту строчку, то artisan ожидает и выполняет свои функции (контроллеры, разумеется, не выполняют свои функции в это время из-за ошибки).
Вопросы:

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Хотел сделать модель "Connect", в которой расположить все функции от Битрикса + мои, но если переношу функцию в класс (функцию, которая спокойно работает в обычном файле, наподобие Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection()), то Laravel выдаёт ошибку Class "App\Models\Bitrix\Main\Application" not found . Как решить это?

Comment: В ларавеле можно настроить сколько угодно не зависимых коннектов к БД, зачем что-то дополнительно подключать?) просто настройте конфиг

Comment: Пытался и таким путём пойти, прописал всё в .env абсолютно правильно (с кавычками всё что нужно, продебажил через Route::get('/env', function () { dd(env('DB_PASSWORD')); });" - получаю SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'.

У нас очень сильно парятся из-за безопасности и максимально закрытый контур Битрикса и мне не дадут ничего с этим сделать, увы.

Хотя, конечно, странно, я с того же сервера обращаюсь, что и Битрикс (ведь мой сервис встройка в Битрикс), с теми же логином/паролем, но ошибка.

Comment: В require отталкивайтесь от текущей директории когда путь прописываете, и везде будет работать. А вообще, весьма странно, потому что ошибка Access denied она же "серверная", бд ip с кредами не пускает, непонятно каким боком при подключении файла это начинает работать

Comment: Попробуйте использовать app_path() для построения полного пути до файла prolog_before.php в require

Comment: Спасибо, решение "сделать путь от запускаемого файла" помогло.
Правда теперь artisan выводит новую ошибку, в Handler почему-то не передаётся ожидаемый class "Bitrix\Main\ORM\Loader" , но это уже видимо другая история :)


 Bitrix\Main\Loader::registerHandler(): Argument #1 ($handler) must be of type callable, array given, called in /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include/autoload.php on line 158

  at /modules/main/lib/loader.php:327

  public static function registerHandler(callable $handler)
    {
\spl_autoload_register($handler);
}